# How to change format of entire text After paste by button click using jQuery in ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to set font family and font size and font color of the text that appears in a ckeditor textarea by clicking the button using jQuery. I don't want to go server side. Please help me.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('#btnPresSet_Font').on('click', '', function() {
  $('#cke_37').find('a').click();
  CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(116, 'Open Sans,Arial,sans-serif');

  $('#cke_38').find('a').click();
  CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(119, '13');

  $('#cke_85').click();
  CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(124, '#4E5F70', 'fore');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting `.on('click', '',` to do, but it's not correct syntax

Comment: ok,i want to set my ckeditor font-size and font-family using  jQuery button onclick event

Comment: Which version of CKEditor are you using? Seeing a working example of your problem would help

Comment: ckeditor 4 i am using